# how to make all columns in the last row as NAN in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

how to make all columns in the last row as NAN in pandas dataframe

I have a DataFrame df which consists of the following,

```
Name     Age     Company       Occupation
Gerald    30     Greenways     Doctor
Tippi     25     Pathsect      Engineer
Herbi     26     Neways        Engineer
```

The end result should contain the following,

```
Name     Age     Company       Occupation
Gerald    30     Greenways     Doctor
Tippi     25     Pathsect      Engineer
NAN       NAN     NAN           NAN
```

I'm new to pandas

Answer (score 0):

Use selection last row and set `NaN`:

```
df.iloc[-1] = np.nan
print (df)
     Name   Age    Company Occupation
0  Gerald  30.0  Greenways     Doctor
1   Tippi  25.0   Pathsect   Engineer
2     NaN   NaN        NaN        NaN
```